# gatling after method not reached

Tags: scala, gatling

Right now I'm having difficulty with a custom gatling feeder despite the fact that it's circular. I'm getting this error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine

I'm reading this is the default behavior. However, I want to make sure each user users a different refurl from the feeder: refUrlFeederBuffer.

Also, why isn't it running my after method? I need my cleanup procedures to run regardless of the success or failure of the simulation. If I don't cleanup I can't restart the test!

```
var refUrlFeeder: Array [Map[String, String]] = Array()

before {
   //create stuff and put the refUrls from it in a map
     refUrlFeeder = refUrlFeeder :+ Map("refUrl" -> simpleUrl)
}

after {
   // delete whatever I created in the before method
   // THIS METHOD DOES NOT EXCUTE if the feeder is emptied
   // I need it to execute regardless of errors during the scenario
}

object ImportRecords {
    val someXml = "<some xml>"
    val feeder = RecordSeqFeederBuilder(refUrlFeeder).circular
    val update =
      feed(feeder)
      exec(http("Update stuff")
       .put("${refUrl}")
       .body(StringBody(someXml))
       .asXML
       .check(status.is(200))
)
}
```

val adminUpdaters = scenario("Admins who do updates").exec(ImportRecords.update)      setUp(adminUpdaters.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpConf))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the feeder runs out of items Gatling stops whole engine. It is exceptional situation which is stated also in exception itself:

```
[error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine
```

Hook `after` is called only when simulation is completed. You can receive the errors in sense of logic in your simulation, but not **developer bugs**. Hook is not called when there is a developer bug, which in this case it is.

Simply running out of feeder is a bug, because it says that your `setUp` part of simulation is not in correlation with your provided data in this case your `feeder`.

Btw. what does your `setUp` part of the simulation looks like?

EDIT: Just looking at your code structure, I'm guessing (while not seeing the whole simulation), that initialisation of your `ImportRecords` happens before hook `before` is called and thus your `val feeder` contains empty array. Making an empty array circular will lead to just another empty array, hence you will get an exception when Gatling tries to take an element from feeder. Try to add:

```
println(refUrlFeeder)
```

into initialisation of your object `ImportRecords` to find out if this is the case.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that and get back to you. I added my setUp to the above code. I definitely agree with you and suspect something is not getting initialized.

Comment: Side comment: in 2.2, after block will be called, even when a feeder runs empty.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for letting me know! I think that makes a lot of sense and will pull in 2.2 then.

Comment: Teliatko, thank you so much. That was indeed what was happening. The above code was wrapped in a class called MySimulation that extended Simulation. I was essentially treating before() as if it were MySimulations's constructer or like Junit's @BeforeClass. I'm realizing now that before is executed before execution of an instantiated scenario. Correct me if I'm wrong though. Regardless you sent me down the right path to resolving this so I've accepted the answer. If I am correct, I wonder if there is an equivalent concept in Gatling to a BeforeClass.

Comment: Happy to hear that :). In relation to BeforeClass, no there isn't nothing I'm aware of.